# Return to caller as a thread (Dont do it)

Tags: python, multithreading

I want a function that checks a file for changes.
Every time it finds a change, it starts a thread and returns flow to the caller.

```
def if_file_changes(file_loc):
    import threading, time 
    with open(file_loc, 'r') as nctn:
        state = nctn.read()
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        with open(file_loc, 'r') as nctn:
            check_state = nctn.read()
        if check_state != state:
            state = check_state
            check_state = None
            t = threading.Thread(return) # How do I return in a thread?
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
```

**Edit:**
I did not understand the problem. I was trying to create the threading at the function level when it should have been at the caller.
My solution is below.

Comment: You can't return to something that you didn't come from initially. A just-started thread in particular has nothing to return to and in particular it can't be told to return to some other thread's calling function. I think you should describe what you want to achieve, because either using a generator to temporarily return to the caller  or using a thread to perform something in parallel is the right choice, but you are asking for a solution to your unspecified problem that is simply not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correction I made was modularizing the caller into functions so that any portion could be repeated as necessary. Then importing the file checker and calling it where needed.

**the function:**

```
def on_file_change(func=None, file_loc=None, start_activated=False):
    import threading, time
    def s():
        with open(file_loc, 'r') as nctn:
            state = nctn.read()
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            with open(file_loc, 'r') as nctn:
                check_state = nctn.read()
            if check_state != state and check_state != None and check_state != '':
                state = check_state
                t = threading.Thread(target=func)
                t.start()
    if start_activated == True:
        t = threading.Thread(target=func)
        t.start()
    s()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implemented *returning a thread* by setting a global value in the new thread:

```
G_THREAD_RET = None

def thread_func():
    #do something here
    G_THERAD_RET = ret

def main():
    #this is the main thread function
    # wait for child thread here
    ret = G_THERAD_RET # get the return value of child thread
```

This is simplest if you only have a few threads to get return value from.

Also, you can pass a param to thread function and set it in the new thread before thread exits:

```
def func(ret=[]):
    time.sleep(2)
    ret.append(2)

def main():
    ret = []
    t = threading.Thread(target=func,args=(ret,))
    t.start()
    t.join()
    print ret
```

You have to use a list for value returning, because only list and dict are mutable in python.

PS: do you really need to read the whole file to check if there are some changes? Checking the time stamp is much more common for detecting file changes.

Comment: You don't need globals for that. All that you need is an object that is accessible by both threads. Then, there are more mutable types than just list and dict. It's probably easier to list the immutable ones: Strings, booleans, integers, tuples are the most prominent ones.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Indeed, I give an example of implementing return value by adding a extra mutable param.